# How to remove only extension from origin file with certain extension recursively in folder?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command

How to remove only extension from origin file with certain extension recursively in folder?

example, If I have

```
/foo/bar/index.html
/foo/bar/error.html
/foo/bar/static/hi.html
/foo/bar/static/me.jpg
/foo/bar/static/you.jpg
/foo/bar/build/yep.html
```

And I expect follows after excute some command

```
/foo/bar/index
/foo/bar/error
/foo/bar/static/hi
/foo/bar/static/me.jpg
/foo/bar/static/you.jpg
/foo/bar/build/yep
```

Thanks for the help.
Please tell some OS's command If command exist (windows, ubuntu/linux)

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a command :

```
ls | find *.html | for f in *.html; do mv $f $(echo $f|sed s/.html//);done
```